# Hyperbolicity and inequality for variety of general type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\BMY{BMY}$Let $(X,H)$ be a smooth, complex, projective, polarized variety of dimension $n\geq3$, whose canonical bundle $K_X$ is big and nef.

1. Is it know whether the inequality $\displaystyle \BMY(X,H)=\int_X\left[c_2(X)-\frac{n}{2(n+1)}c_1(X)^2\right]\cdot H^{n-2}\geq0$ holds?
2. If $\BMY(X,H)=0$ then $X$ is uniformized by the unit ball $\mathbb{B}^n$, and in particular $X$ is hyperbolic. Is it kwnow wether the inverse implication holds?, I mean if $X$ is uniformized by $\mathbb{B}^n$ then does $\BMY(X,H)$ vanish?

---

[1] R. Brody - *Compact Manifolds and Hyperbolicity*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **235** (1978) 213-219.

[2] S. Kobayashi (2005) *Hyperbolic Manifolds And Holomorphic Mappings. An Introduction. (Second Edition)* World Scientific.

[3] C. T. Simpson - *Constructing variations of Hodge structure using Yang-Mills theory and applications to uniformization*, J. Amer. Math. Soc. **1** (1988) 867-918.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ admits a Kähler-Einstein metric [Theorem 2,3] and [Theorem 1,2], if $K_X$ is ample the inequality holds with $H=K_X$, by [Theorem IV.4.16,1].

---

[1] S. Kobayashi (1987) *Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles*, Iwanami Shoten Publishers and Princeton University Press.

[2] S.-T. Yau - *Calabi's conjecture and some new results in algebraic geometry*, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. **74** (1977) 1798-1799.

[3] S.-T. Yau - *On the Ricci curvature of a compact Kähler manifold and the complex Monge-Ampère equation. I*, Comm. Pure Appl. Math. **31** (1978) 339-411.